# Remove a file from whole git history

Tags: git, commit, git-rm

I know this question has already been asked, but in every answer, I found the situation is slightly different from mine and I don't see how to adapt it.

So here is the problem:

I cloned a repository and added a folder to work in it. In this folder, I added .csv files and .py files that use the csv ones.
I tried to push this but realised it was taking to long as 2 csv files are very big. So i

```
git rm files
```

and then commit. I tried to push again and only then realised that removing a file doesn't remove it from the git history .//
So now, from the last completed push, I have 2 commits: 1 where I added the files, 1 where I deleted some .csv.

I would like your help to delete the last 2 commits. Is that feasible?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I find the first example in the `git filter-branch` doc very fitting to your context. Take a look ([source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)) :

> Suppose you want to remove a file (containing confidential information or copyright violation) from all commits:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm filename' HEAD
# and see also the variant further in the example description
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' HEAD
```

(see the details on the doc page, I refrained from copy-pasting the whole thing here)

Answer (score 1):

filter-branch, as has been advised is fine if we are talking about biiiig histories. If we are talking of only a handful of revisions, you can do it (remove the files) by just amend the revision where you added the file and cherry-pick, or rebase interactive.

One example..... say I added file a.txt on master~2. I don't want it on the history anymore.

`git checkout master~2
git rm --cached a.txt
git commit --amend --no-edit
git cherry-pick master~2..master
git branch -f master # point master in this revision
git checkout master`

That should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

> ... I would like ... to delete the last 2 commits. Is that feasible?

You can't quite *delete* commits, but you can easily tell Git to *forget* them.

The way this works is pretty simple, in the end.  We start by noting that each commit saves a snapshot, and also stores the hash ID of its *parent* commit (along with your commit log message and your name as author and so on).  This forms a backwards-pointing chain of commits.

If we let single uppercase letters stand in for commit hash IDs, we can draw this chain:

```
... <-F  <-G  <-H   <--master
```

Note that the *branch name*, `master` in this case, stores the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  (When something stores the hash ID of a commit, we say that this thing *points to* the commit, hence the arrows.  The name `master` points to `H`, `H` points to `G`, and so on.)

The way Git finds these commits is to read the hash ID of `H` out of `master`, which locates commit `H`, then read commit `H` and show it.  Then, having read `H`, Git has the hash ID of commit `G`, so Git can read `G` and show it, and so on.

When we make a new commit, Git actually does this by:

- writing out the snapshot;
- writing out the author and log message and so on;
- having the *new* point back to the *current* commit;
- and last, but most important, writing the hash ID of the *new* commit into the branch name.

So if we had:

```
...--F--G--H
```

and we added `--I`:

```
...--F--G--H--I
```

then Git has changed the *name* `master` to store the hash ID of commit `I`.  Eventually we have:

```
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- master
```

If we made several unwanted commits, we can tell Git: *Re-set the name `master` to point to commit `H` instead of commit `J`.*  There are several ways to do that, but the first one to reach for, in this case, is `git reset --hard` (while we have `master` checked out, and be sure you don't have anything you are concerned with losing, because `git reset --hard` tells Git to throw *everything* out):

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

The `~2` suffix tells Git to count back two steps—technically, two *first parent* steps, which matters when we have some merge commits in our chain, but here, we don't so it does not matter.  If `master` currently points to `J`, that has Git count back twice: `J` to `I`, then `I` to `H`.  Git then replaces our work with the contents from commit `H` *and* makes the name, `master`, point to `H` instead of `J`:

```
             I--J
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

Now that `J` is hard to *find*, it *appears* to be deleted.

The drawback to this is that if we've had our Git tell some other Git: *Here, take copies of commits `I` and `J`,* that other Git has the two commits and will *re-introduce* them to our own Git even after our Git has forgotten them.  But if we have never successfully sent the two commits anywhere else, we're the only one who *has* them, so if *we* forget them, they're as good as gone.

(If we *have* pushed them, we can have our Git, and *their* Git, and *every other Git* that has picked them up since then, *all* forget them, and *then* they will be gone.  But obviously this gets hard quickly.)